# Preposterositions

Tags: phrase-meaning, reference

OK, as a German I'm a bit the pot calling the kettle black, but when I heard "Detroit Rock City" by Kiss ("Get up, everybody gonna move their feet, get down, everybody gonna leave their seat") I always was imagining a wild crowd jumping up and down. Even if the context gives a hint! (It didn't help that Gilbert O'Sullivan's "Get Down" *actually* points downward, so to say, and has a completely different meaning.)

Other example made up by me: "He was living it up, now he can't manage living it down."

Can you add one or two examples where "verb up" and "verb down" aren't opposites (better, even not really specifying a direction)? Or even better give me a link, avoiding the dreaded Long List? (Same with "on" and "off", etc.)

Comment: If you ask for one or two examples, I don't think you have to fear The Long List. Besides, requests for resources are off-topic on the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble with idiomatic expressions is they don't necessarily have an opposite, or even a logical derivation. There may be another idiom using the opposite direction, yet it doesn't mean the reverse of the first. Confused?

> Living it up - living in style, enjoying oneself, partying.
> Living it down - struggling to survive admonition/peer pressure because of some embarrassment, your fault or not.

"His wife left him. Ran off with a footballer."
"How will he ever live it down?"

> Rip it up - either tear it into small pieces or again another 'party' implication.
> Rip it down - [of, for instance, a poster on the wall] literally tear it from the wall, an act of destruction.

Get down can mean either a direction, or nothing to do with directions.

> Get down off the ladder - a literal direction of travel.
> Get down & boogie - 'Dance'. No implied direction at all.

> Off his head - drunk or on drugs, or 'mad'.
> On his head - fell badly, or is doing headstands or is wearing a hat.
> Off with his head - decapitate him.
> Off with the fairies - not paying attention.
> Off of the telly - famous for appearing on TV. [Terrible English but a common knowing misuse.]

> Landed on his head - fell badly & was possibly injured.
> Landed on his feet - was lucky in getting out of a situation [unrelated to standing].

Basically - you cannot guess these. You have to know.

Comment: There was the story that a large number of Kiss fans were killed in Vietnam because when the command 'Get down!' was given, they all got up and started boogying.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yeah, that sounds ..credible :D